# GWT not starting by not finding appengine-web.xml

Tags: java, gwt

I'm dealing with a problem that I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. When I try to run the development server using Run As -> Web Application, I get the following error on the console:

```
Initializing App Engine server
Feb 07, 2014 8:39:07 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing C:\Users\JOSR\Last Hope\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate C:\Users\JOSR\Last Hope\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:140)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:399)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:146)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:60)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:84)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\JOSR\Last Hope\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
... 23 more
```

I know that the path "C:\Users\JOSR\Last Hope\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml" is wrong, should be "C:\Users\JOSR\Last Hope\war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml", but I don't know where to change it or how to force GWT to use the proper war path. Any ideas?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from context-menu

**Run As/Run Configuration** and  select your html ,choose Arguments tab

-war option is that.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I started using Maven in a GWT-GAE project.

In my case this problem happened because the eclipse launch file tries to load the appengine-web.xml from `target/myproject/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` but the files are in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

The solution is to uncheck the option "Launch and deploy from this directory (disabled because this is a Maven project)" from your project properties in Eclipse, even if this is really a maven project, like in the picture the option "WAR directory:" should point `src/main/webapp`

**Important**! Keep in mind, you have to build the project using maven before running the launch file, otherwise the folder `target/myproject/WEB-INF/` will be empty.

[image]